# Creating an Executable App

Tags: application

The `CreateExecutable` and `Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]` commands can run .exe applications in MMA. I would like to know if it is possible to make this module as an executable, since it is part of a toolbox that I have created. I have installed VS 2013 and VS 2015.This is the module:

```
reloj = Framed[
  Dynamic[Refresh[
    ClockGauge[DateString["Time"], ImageSize -> 120, 
     LabelStyle -> {Darker@Black, 10.5, Bold}, 
     GaugeStyle -> {Red, Red, Black}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], LabelStyle -> Bold, 
     GaugeLabels -> {"ROLEX", Placed["AMPM", {0.5, 0.35}]}, 
     GaugeMarkers -> "ThinArrowNeedle"], UpdateInterval -> 1]], 
  RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> LightBlue]
```

This is an example of what I want to do with the clock module.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CreateExecutable["#include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
 printf(\"hello world\\n\");
 }
 ", "hello"]
```

Comment: Is the goal to have something that can execute in an environment external to the Mathematica user interface? If so, I cannot imagine that the run time library would support `Dynamic` and `Refresh`.

Comment: I am not an expert here but related documentation implies that you can create an .exe only from things that are compilable. And gui elements are not: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/5478

Comment: @Kuba. I checked the link documentation and, effectively, Refresh and Dynamic are not on the list, so the question has no solution in my opinion. Thank you both for your comments.